# Changing icons dynamically in ListView with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, android-adapter

I'm using a custom adapter to define the items of a `ListView`. Each item is a post (just like a forum) defined by its idpost in my DB and has 3 `ImageViews` that should allow users to mark that post as favorite, edit it and delete it (if the user is the author of the post).

I'm having troubles to develop this behavior. Here is my adapter so far.

```
public class ComentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Comentario>    mDataset;
    private LayoutInflater      mLayoutInflater;
    private Context             mContext;

    public class ViewHolder {

        public ImageView    imAvatar;
        public TextView     tvAutor;
        public TextView     tvDestinatario;
        public TextView     tvFecha;
        public TextView     tvContenido;
        public TextView     tvArchivo;
        public TextView     tvRespuestas;
        public ImageView    imFav;
        public ImageView    imEditar;
        public ImageView    imBorrar;

    }

    public ComentAdapter(Context context, List<Comentario> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mDataset = items;
    }

    public void setDataset(List<Comentario> newDataset) {
        mDataset = newDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Comentario getItem(int position) {
        return mDataset.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.comentario_list_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imAvatar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imAvatar);
            holder.tvAutor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAutor);
            holder.tvDestinatario = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDestinatario);
            holder.tvFecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFecha);
            holder.tvContenido = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContenido);
            holder.tvArchivo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvArchivo);
            holder.tvRespuestas = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRespuestas);
            holder.imFav = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imFav);
            holder.imEditar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imEditar);
            holder.imBorrar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imBorrar);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(getItem(position).getFoto_autor()).into(holder.imAvatar);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

When the `ImageView` imFav is clicked I should mark/unmark that post as favorite in the DB AND change the icon. This works, showing the idpost (just before `return convertView;`):

```
// idcomentario is the idpost I mentioned
holder.imFav.setTag(getItem(position).idcomentario);

holder.imFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "" + holder.imFav.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

But I have some troubles when I want to change de icon. I tried these two solutions (inside the `onClick(View v)` method above):

```
((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_relleno);
```

And

```
holder.imFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_relleno);
```

The icon changes, but that change is missed when the ListView scrolls. I know I have to notify changes like this:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But I can't use `adapter` here, it should be in my activity.java I guess. So I tried to set onClick in my item_layout.xml.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imFav"
    ...
    android:onClick="onClickFav" />
```

And in the activity.java

```
public void onClickFav(View v) {
    ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_relleno);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But that doesn't work. Nothing changes.

Does anybody know how to make this works? That is my main question, but I'd like to know too if there is any way to manage all the OnClickListener out of the adapter. In the activity.java or, even better, in a new class?

Sorry for making the post that long, but I wanted to expose as much information as possible.

Comment: you must update your underlying data in mDataset. Because when items in list is scrolled it reload again from your mDataset via adapter

Answer (score 0):

your Comentario class must have methods like

> boolean isFavorite()

and

> void setFavorite(boolean favorite)

then need to set [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to your listView

then in onItemClick() toggle favorite state

```
@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // toggle favorite state
    getItem(position).setFavorite(!getItem(position).isFavorite());
}
```

in  public View getView add this:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(getItem(position).getFoto_autor()).into(holder.imAvatar);
Picasso.with(mContext).load(getItem(position).isFavorite()? R.drawable.favorite : R.drawable.not_favorite).into(holder.imAvatar);
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer. My Comentario class do have those two methods you mentioned. How should I set AdapterView.OnItemClickListener to my listView? And where should I copy the `onItemClick` method?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener). use listView.setOnItemClickListener(mOnItemClickListener); instead of set OnClickListener for each Item in list

Comment: Ok, I just did it. But maybe I didn't explain myself, I don't want to do anything `onItemClick`, I want to do something "`OnViewInsideItemClick`", I mean, when users clicks in a view (`ImageView` in this case) inside an item.